# cant access node RESTfull API's from outside company network

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, https, windows-firewall

I have deployed express REST full application which is listening on port xxxx in server A. Express Application is behind firewall due to security issues. Also have angular application deployed in another server B, which is NOT behind firewall and is accessing the express REST full API's deployed in server A. If i access Angular application from inside company network, application is able to get response from express REST full API's. But If i access Angular application from outside company network application is NOT able to get response from express REST full API's. What networking/firewall changes am supposed to do to get endpoints access from Angular application from outside company network also?? I have tried creating new inbound rules for port xxxx in firewall but not able to get working.

Comment: This isn't really about programming; it's about administration. If you can provide more detail about your setup, you might be able to get an answer on [sf] or [webmasters.se], but do read their help centers to make sure it's on topic.

Comment: you should try setting both inbound and outbound rules for this port on your firewall